# How can i fix double for loop in django

Tags: python, django, templates

lostList.html shows LostNotices and Dogs.

I want to match lostnotice and dog using foreign key in Dog model.

So i used for loop and if in the template.

But it doesn't work....

I am trying to fix this for 2 days but i couldn't.

It will be really big help for me. Thank you

```
{% for lostPost in lostPosts.all reversed %}
              <h6>{{lostPost.id}}</h6>
              {% for dog in dogs.all %}
              <h6>{{dog.breed}}</h6><br>



              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    {% if dog.LostNoticeNum == lostPost.id %}
```

views.py

```
def lostList(request):
    lostPosts = LostNotice.objects
    dogs=Dog.objects
    return render(request, '/lostList.html', {'lostPosts' : lostPosts,'dogs':dogs})
```

model.py

```
class LostNotice(models.Model):
    Title=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    State=models.IntegerField()
    PubDate=models.DateTimeField()
    MissingDate=models.DateTimeField()
    Text=models.TextField()
    Phone=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    Author=models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)

    Si=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    Gu=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    Dong=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)

class Dog(models.Model): 
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Breed=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Sex=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    Color=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    LostNoticeNum=models.ForeignKey(LostNotice, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    FindNoticeNum=models.ForeignKey(FindNotice, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

template:

```
<div class="" id="list">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mx-auto">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-12 pr-1">
            <div class="row mb-2 ml-2 mr-2">

              {% for lostPost in lostPosts.all reversed %}
              <h6>{{lostPost.id}}</h6>
              {% for dog in dogs.all %}
              <h6>{{dog.breed}}</h6><br>



              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    {% if dog.LostNoticeNum == lostPost.id %}
                    <h6>breed</h6>
                    <h6 class="card-title" style="text-align: center; color: gray">{{dog.Breed}}</h6>
                    {% else %}
                    <h6 class="card-title" style="text-align: center">{{lostPost.sex}}</h6>

                    {% endif %}
                    {{lostPost.photo}}
                    {% if lostPost.photo %}
                    <img class="card-img-top rounded-circle mx-auto pt-1" src="{{ lostPost.photo.url }}"
                      style="height: 200px">
                    {% else %}
                    <img class="card-img-top rounded-circle mx-auto pt-1"
                      src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2138/2138440.svg" style="height: 200px">



                    <h4 class="card-title">{{lostPost.pet_name}}</h4>
                    <p class="card-text"> text: {{lostPost.Text}} <br> location: {{lostPost.Si}}<br>date :
                      {{lostPost.MissingDate}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'lostListDetail' %}" class="btn btn-primary">more</a>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the related dogs with `.dog_set.all`:

```
{% for lostPost in lostPosts reversed %}
    <h6>{{lostPost.id}}</h6>
    {% for dog in lostPost.dog_set.all %}
        <h6>{{dog.breed}}</h6><br>
        …
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the view, you pass a queryset with `.prefetch_related`:

```
def lostList(request):
    lostPosts = LostNotice.objects.prefetch_related('dog')
    dogs=Dog.objects
    return render(request, '/lostList.html', {'lostPosts' : lostPosts})
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! But i don't know where 'dog_set' and 'prefetch_related('dog')' came from. There is no 'dog' attribute in LostNotice model... And is it okay to use double for loop like that??

Comment: @YeinKoo: no, a double for loop like that is not only "ugly" (in the sense that you need to read it to understand it), it is also very inefficient. Imagine that later you have 1M dogs, an 1M lostPosts, then this will take 1T cycles (whereas accessing the `dog_set` will stil result in 1M cycles). The `dog_set` (and `dog`) is implicitly defined: by defining a `ForeignKey` from `Dog` to `LostNotice`, Django defines a relation in reverse.

Comment: @YeinKoon: so you do *not* need to define `dog` at  all. Django defined the relation in reverse for you, and it is capable of loading and fetching objects by the relation in reverse itself.

Comment: oh i see. The by using prefetch_related i don't have to use double for loop! is that right?

Comment: @YeinKoo: the idea is that Django will fetch all the related dogs, and do joining at the Python/Django layer, and thus avoids the N+1 problem https://riptutorial.com/django/example/8219/reduce-number-of-queries-on-foreignkey-field--nplus1-issue- . In the template we still have a nested `{% for %}` loop, but the `lostPost.dog_set.all` only contain the *related* dogs.

Comment: thanks for kind explanation. I'll try those solutions that you've told me!